# Can I get the code for the local currency from an NSLocale?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nslocale

Can I get the code for the local currency from an NSLocale?  I tried this:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"] autorelease];
NSString *currencyCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
```

but currencyCode comes back as nil (I wanted "EUR", or similar).

Comment: This work for me. This is not a memory problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine for me in a regular Macintosh app.

```
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"] autorelease];
NSString *currencyCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
NSLog( @"currencyCode is %@", currencyCode );
```

displays this in the console:

```
2011-11-14 14:53:33.784 Testing[26388:707] currencyCode is EUR
```

Are you trying to build this as a command line (Foundation) app or something non-traditional-Mac-like?

Comment: iPhone, rather than Mac.  Could that be it?

Comment: Same code works on my iPhone, Simon. Try dropping those lines of code into a brand new iPhone app (like I just did), just for testing, and you should see that they do work for you.  I think something else is going on with your iPhone app.  You should remove the "osx" tag from this question, b.t.w.  :-)

Comment: BTW, the locale is autoreleased, so isn't that a double release in your last line?

Comment: Ah - found my mistake; I was actually passing @"fr" not @"fr_FR" to initWithLocaleIdentifier:.  Serves me right for not posting my full code.

Comment: in my case i had to get it dynamically so used `NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];` rest is all the same.. Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

`NSLocale` has a method called [`- objectForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLocale/objectForKey:) that returns an object corresponding to a specified 
`NSLocale` component key passed as a parameter. With Swift 2.2, `- objectForKey:` has the following declaration:

```
func objectForKey(_ key: AnyObject) -> AnyObject?
```

Among the many [`NSLocale` component keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSLocale_Component_Keys), Apple states about `NSLocaleCurrencyCode`:

> The key for the currency code associated with the locale. The corresponding value is an `NSString` object; for example, "USD".

---

Therefore, you can retrieve the currency code linked to a `NSLocale` instance with the following Swift 2.2 and Swift 3 code snippets:

*Swift 2.2*

```
import Foundation

let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fr_FR")
//let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let localeCurrencyCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as! String
print(localeCurrencyCode) // prints "EUR"
```

*Swift 3*

```
import Foundation

let locale = Locale(localeIdentifier: "fr_FR")
//let locale = Locale.current
let localeCurrencyCode = locale.object(forKey: Locale.Key.currencyCode) as! String
print(localeCurrencyCode) // prints "EUR"
```